# Brushless Motors kv rating and testing methods/procedures

Tags: drone

I’m very interested in testing Brushless motors and Prop sizes.

I have been involved with ASTM ASHTO and other testing methods.

What procedures/standards are used for testing brushless motors for the purpose of manufacturing?

I want to learn to use these procedures and I don’t know where to find them.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Usually I just spin the motor and measure the phase voltage with an oscilloscope to measure Kv. I am not aware of any standard on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

**Kv** or 'velocity constant' is the ratio of rotational velocity to applied voltage, usually specified in rpm per Volt. There are 3 ways to measure it:-

1. Spin the motor shaft at a known rpm, while measuring the generated
   peak voltage with an oscilloscope or peak-reading meter.
2. Connect the motor to a controller and run it *unloaded* at
   full throttle, while measuring the supply voltage and motor rpm.
3. Run the motor at full throttle with different loads, measuring
   Volts, Amps and rpm for each load. Then calculate kV by
   extrapolating the rpm curve to what it would be at zero current draw.

Rpm can be measured with a tachometer on the shaft, or electrically by the measuring the frequency of one phase terminal. If measured electrically you must divide by the number of magnet poles to get mechanical rpm.

Method 1 has the advantage that you don't need a controller, but driving the motor mechanically can be tricky.

Method 2 is easiest if the motor is already connected to a controller and/or installed in a device. However the kV value will be a little low due to voltage drop in the motor's internal resistance, which reduces the effective applied voltage.

Method 3 takes into account the combined characteristics of motor + controller, and also provides enough data to determine the other motor constants, **Rm** ('dynamic' resistance) and **Io** (no-load current).

With **Kv**, **Rm** and **Io** characterized you can calculate the motor's performance under any load.

Comment: I believe that Kv, TECHNICALLY is the ratio of RPM to back EMF amplitude. Back EMF vs applied voltage.

Comment: @mkeith rpm/back-emf yes, and when powered the motor speeds up until back-emf = supply voltage - I*Rm. Rm is difficult to measure directly but can be deduced from the rpm slope as loading is increased. I have tested many 'hobby' motors and found some with actual Kv values much higher than spec, suggesting that the rating was obtained by (incorrectly) dividing no-load rpm by supply voltage. http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/test_data.html

Comment: In your first sentence you said ratio of rotational velocity to applied voltage. I was trying to suggest that maybe you could change "applied voltage" to "back EMF amplitude" or something similar. It is a good answer with info in it that I didn't really think about before. I upvoted it.